# C++ overloading operators

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm stuck with overloading operators "+", "-", "/" and "*" in my program.
Basically I've got an object, which is dynamically allocated array of double values.
I've got the whole program, but I can't get through those overloads.

my constructor looks like this:

```
table::table(int size) {
    this->size = size;
    tab = new double[size];
    count++;
}
```

I've wrote something like that:

```
table & table::operator-(const table &tab3 )
{
        table * tab_oper2 = new table(size);
        for(int i=0; i< tab3.size; i++) 
        {
            (*this).tab[i] -= tab3.tab[i];
        }
        return *this;
}
```

which generally works, but It's not generally good way to do it.
My instructor told me to try to switch (*this) to *tab_oper2, return it as a reference but
it doesn't work.
Please, could someone tell me how to do it properly?

Comment: Don't modify `this` in `operator-`. Create a new `table` with something like `table tab_oper2`. Manipulate the new table and return it by value.

Comment: Alternatively, implement `operator-=` to modify `this` in place. Then, as long as the type is copyable, it's very easy to implement `operator-` in terms of that.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You are allocating a result table but you are not populating it.  Populate the result table and it will work.

```
table & table::operator-(const table &tab3 )
{
        table * tab_oper2 = new table(size);
        for(int i=0; i< tab3.size; i++) 
        {
            tab_oper2->tab[i] = tab[i] - tab3.tab[i];
        }
        return *tab_oper2;
}
```

Comment: it will also leak since you will return a reference to an allocated pointer that will not be cleaned up.

Comment: For all we know, he's using a GC with his C++

Comment: @antlersoft: because he doesn't have delete in his code ? his just a mistake I think

Comment: Thanks alot! this one works fine! and @up, I do have a destructor, didn't posted it. Maybe I should have done it.

Comment: @MichałBujak: You have a destructor, but who `delete` the `tab_oper2` after exiting the function ?!

Comment: "For all we know, he's using a GC with his C++", whaaat? That's a serious memory leak dude.

Answer (score 5):

C++ is a value oriented language; return a `table` (and not a `table&`).  Construct the return value in a local variable, and return it.  And don't forget the rule of three: given the little code you've shown, you'll need a copy constructor, an assignment operator and a destructor.  (Of course, if you use `std::vector`, rather than `new[]`, all of this will be taken care of for you.)